# Geeting issue fetch data when 'DATE' field datatype is TEXT in database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch data between two range but in my database Date field as Text. How Now fetch data between two range

```
     $startdate = 01-01-2020
     $enddate = 31-12-2020
```

and my database field name DATE as text datatype(format 01-12-2019) Below is the query I am using

```
       SELECT * FROM F_RI_DETAILS 
        where COST_CENTER = 152 
        AND (DATE BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '31-12-2020')
```

Please help how to get data with text datattype in database. How to convert text to date and fetch all data .
Now cant change column type in database.
Please help me

Comment: Show DDL for `F_RI_DETAILS`.

Comment: Review data functions here particularly str_to_date https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: *cant change column type in database.* Add generated column of DATE datatype with proper expression.

Comment: @Akina DDL  ,
ID  int(11) PRIMARY_KEY     auto_increment
DATE    text         
DESC_EXPENSE    text          
COST_CENTER text          
EXPENSE_CURRENCY    text          
AMT_REPT_CUR    text         
CONVERSION_RATE text          
AMOUNT  text

Comment: Edit the question, please, DDL in a comment is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM f_ri_details 
WHERE cost_center = 152 
  AND (STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31')
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM f_ri_details 
WHERE cost_center = 152 
  AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = 2020
```

or even

```
SELECT * 
FROM f_ri_details 
WHERE cost_center = 152 
  AND RIGHT(`date`, 4) = '2020'
```